# Does my Facebook app need to be made live?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am currently building an analytics dashboard that consumes client data from various API's (Google Analytics, Mailchimp etc).

Now I'm at the point of hooking it up to the Facebook Graph API (v3.x) and I am currently able to pull in a pages fan_count utilising a Long Lived token whilst the App is in development mode.

My question is - this app isnt going to be publicly accessible and only provides my Laravel installation with this fan_count metric so do I need to worry about putting it into Live mode and submitting it for review? As far as I understand, I can dynamically request the access to token to be refreshed anyway so in theory I dont see any reason for me to ever need to make the app 'live'.

Just looking for confirmation that my understanding is correct.

Thanks

Jay

Comment: Do you only need this for your own pages? If your customers are supposed to login and grant access to _their_ pages, then you should rather (submit it for review and) set it live, otherwise you would have to add them all to a role in the app (and that again will only work if they have their user accounts registered as developers on Facebook.)

Comment: Plus, Rate Limits are different for apps in dev mode. But as long as you are not running into the limits with what you are doing, that would not mean you _have_ to take it live either.

Comment: We manage pages on behalf of clients so will always be accessing it as the 'Admin' user so in essence they would always be our pages. If I am able to get this data under the in-development status then I could just run the API request once a day and cache the response to avoid hitting any rate limits I guess.

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine. As long as you only have to read data (and such rather small amounts at that), and not publish anything (because anything published via an app is only visible to everyone if the app’s public.)

Comment: Great thanks - I just wish that the documentation was a little clear on these use cases.